# Is there an API to invoke Windows Dictation Commands programmatically?

Tags: c#, windows-10, voice, microsoft-speech-api, dictation

Windows 10 provides support for Dictation and modifying the dictated text using voice commands like "Delete word", "New line" e.t.c

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/use-voice-typing-to-talk-instead-of-type-on-your-pc-fec94565-c4bd-329d-e59a-af033fa5689f#WindowsVersion=Windows_10

Is there an API that can be used to invoke these actions programmatically instead of voice?